# How to get all td tags that contain specified text inside using xpath Java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The actual problem is: cannot find all `td` tags which have specified text inside, just some of them.

I'm trying to check if all `td` tags contain specified text using xpath like:

```
 WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.id("tablepress-6"));
 if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + textInput + "')]")).isEmpty()) {

 List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ textInput + "')]"));
          //...
 }
```

Also I've tried methods using xpath like:

```
List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + textInput + "')]"));
```

And like:

```
List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[*[text() = '"+ textInput + "']]/td[2]"));
```

But if I check my [website](https://openscience.in.ua/ua-journals) I'm not getting all matches for `td` elements, maybe because of `br` elements inside some of matched `td`.

[image]

Instead of getting all `17` matches (like on the screen above), I'm getting less number of matches (in my specific case - `12`):
[image]

Can someone suggest me the way how to get all `td` tags which contain specified text? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There're 12 results with `//td[contains(text(),'Physics and astronomy')]` locator on the page, not 17

Comment: Yes, but is it correct if on the website I have 17 results? as you can see my screen, I have more matches than locator gives me.

Comment: @invzbl3 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Probably, you're right. Can you recommend me, please, what exactly to edit? I'm trying to improve xpath which will find me all 17 results for specified text from `td` elements, as you can see my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is case sensitive of `Physics and astronomy`. In some rows you can find **Physics and Astronomy**. To solve the it, you can use xpath [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) function.

In example below, I get second column only with **physics and astronomy** text, because it exist also in the second column.

```
//tr[@role='row']/td[2][contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'physics and astronomy')]
```

As alternative, you can use Java to filter by text:

```
List<WebElement> rows = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".tablepress tbody tr[role=row]")));

// By whole phrase
List<WebElement> physicsAndAstronomy1 = rows.stream().filter(e ->
        e.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(2)")).getText().toLowerCase()
                .contains("physics and astronomy"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// By separately words
List<WebElement> physicsAndAstronomy2 = rows.stream().filter(e -> {
    String text = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(2)")).getText().toLowerCase();
    return text.contains("physics") && text.contains("astronomy");
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about `case sensitive`, Sers. It's actually very useful. I'll try to adapt your examples to get the desired result. If it helps me, I'll mark it also as acceptable.

Comment: In my example `translate` converts element's text to lowercase and check it with 
 `physics and astronomy`. It does what you ask.